# Get the time corresponding to the start of the current calendar month

Tags: ruby, datetime

How can I get a `Time` object corresponding to the start of the current calendar month? E.g., if I ran the function today I'd get a `Time` object for 7/1/2010 at midnight

**Bonus question:** How can I do the same thing for the current **week**? If I ran this function today I'd get a `Time` object for 7/11/2010 at midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' ActiveSupport has helpers for all such things (`beginning_of_month`, `beginning_of_week`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
 Date.civil(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1)
```

Bonus, to get the Sunday:

```
Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cweek - 1, 7)
```

To get the Monday

```
Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cweek, 1)
```

Resources: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html

Edit: I changed my mind on the Sunday, you would have issues at the beginning of a year.  So I would do this instead to get sunday

```
Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cweek, 1) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Time.utc(Time.new.year,Time.new.month)
```

Also see Time.gm, Time.local (whatever you require)